# django multiple response (attach pdf and update template)

Tags: django, csv, response

I need to attach a csv file and refresh the website with parameters from view.py, I have this:

(context have parameters for template)

```
    if create_csv == 1:
    response_CSV = export_csv(request, pat_list, context, template)
    return response_CSV
```

....

```
  def export_csv(request, queryset, context, template):
    import csv
    from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
    response = HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= filter.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response, csv.excel)
    response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
    writer.writerow([
        smart_str(u"Name"),
        smart_str(u"Age"),
    ])
    for obj in queryset:
        writer.writerow([
            smart_str(obj.Name),
            smart_str(obj.age),
        ])
    return response
```

this code only send download file but don't refresh the website with the parameters of the content, Can I do it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I also think your way of doing it might be wrong. You should represent the result in your page according to the parameters first, then user can download the content of your page as csv. Not download csv according to the parameters, then refresh the page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, the best way I think is put a link and download after rendered the page